How to train Mamba with custom time series data
I am consider to build a model for my custom time series data, which has over 400,000 time points for each sequence. Recently, I found that MAMBA is very effective model for long sequence like that. However, I come to their github (https://github.com/state-spaces/mamba/tree/main) and I cannot find a way to input data for training. Could you please show me the source code or how to prepare data for MAMBA input.
In addition, the time points delta_t (the distance between 2 time points) is varied, but in MAMBA, they input dt_min and dt_max into the model parameters, I confuse how they can control the time variant as they mentioned in their paper.
I looking for the other implementation version, but seem that the "Hardware-aware State Expansion" is skipped, so that I come back to the original versions from the MAMBA author
Hope to receive your help!

MAMBA models require input data formatted into sequences with a specified context length and variable time intervals (delta_t) - managed by defining the range with dt_min and dt_max parameters. Preprocessing is essential to ensure these intervals align with the model's expectations.
Both of the github repos contain implementations that may help understand how to preprocess raw data into sequences and structure them for the DataLoader:
https://github.com/Prismadic/simple-CMamba
https://github.com/tanaymeh/mamba-train
There is a script in the CMamba repo 'train.py', in the train function (def train(args):) it uses train_loader and test_loader to batch and feed data into the model (loaders are initialized with train_dataset and test_dataset).

are those github links relevant? why did you post them? please explain

Both of the github repos contain implementations that may help understand how to preprocess raw data into sequences and structure them for the DataLoader.

There is a script in the CMamba repo 'train.py', in the train function (def train(args):) it uses train_loader and test_loader to batch and feed data into the model (loaders are initialized with train_dataset and test_dataset).

could you edit your answer to add what you just said in the comments? it would greatly improve it

absolutely, glad I could contribute!
